Updating kotlin version does not solve "Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. " when running flutter after added firebase
I added firebase into my project and when I try to run, it always give me this error.
e: E:/gradle/caches/transforms-3/c0b55b67018ed7528c3fb574e8fcae45/transformed/jetified-play-services-measurement-api-22.0.0-api.jar!/META-INF/java.com.google.android.gmscore.integ.client.measurement_api_measurement_api.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction

I updated the kotlin version mutliple times but it still the same. The solutions I found suggest to update the kotlin version and it does not work for me. I use vscode for my project.
This is my buildscript in android\build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}


Try updating the ext.kotlin_version to 1.9.0
